# How to linking in realm js

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I just need a simple linking in realm js. I have some predefined cars in Car.
How can I create a Person with just linking more of cars? Can I take this only with the model.value? The model is uniqe.

```
const CarSchema = {
  name: 'Car',
  properties: {
    make:  'string',
    model: 'string',
    miles: {type: 'int', default: 0},
  }
};

const PersonSchema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    name:     'string',
    cars:     {type: 'list', objectType: 'Car'},
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a primary key if the model is unique you can set it as a unique key and then you will start linking